# CRM 2013: Getting Data from Organization Service with Microsoft.Xrm

Tags: c#, soap, crm, xrm

I am trying to get data using my Organization.svc and C#

This code successfully gets the data the first time it is run. 
However, when I call it again, it gets called again, the data pulls nearly instantaneously.

I disabled my internet connection, and found that it was still getting data.

I'm not sure if my data is being cached locally, but it certainly is not coming from my CRM server.

What can I do to get the actual data after the first call?

```
    // CONSTANTS DEFINED UP HERE 
    // (SERVICE_URI, USERNAME, PASSWORD, TIME_ENTITY_NAME,GUID, TIME_QTY)
    //

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            CrmConnection connection = new CrmConnection();
            connection.ServiceUri = new Uri(SERVICE_URI);
            connection.ClientCredentials = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials();
            connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = USERNAME;
            connection.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = PASSWORD;
            using (CrmOrganizationServiceContext context = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(connection))
            {

                try
                {
                    Entity entity = context.Retrieve(TIME_ENTITY_NAME, GUID, new ColumnSet(TIME_QTY));

                    Console.WriteLine(entity.Attributes[TIME_QTY]);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( e.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
```

Comment: CRM will cache the second identical cal.. If you change your query parameters you will get fresh data.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the resolution to it. Btw, i didn't know that. It will come handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to take a closer look at the **CrmOrganizationServiceContext** object I created.

I had to remove the entity from the cache.

```
try { 
    Entity entity = context.Retrieve(TIME_ENTITY_NAME, GUID, new ColumnSet(TIME_QTY));
    context.TryRemoveFromCache(entity); // <- This fixed the cache issue.
    Console.WriteLine(entity.Attributes[TIME_QTY]); 
}
```